# Log out of the site

Tags: support, login

How do I log out of this site? The answer I found says I should click on the Stack Exchange logo on the upper left to logout, but there's no such option.

Also, what is with "This question body does not meet our quality standards.."? I can't even get proper help here.. this is just madness!

Comment: It's in the upper right under the Stack Exchange icon above Ask Question

Comment: Regarding the quality issue, please see both our [tour] and [ask] pages for advice on how to ask a good question. We're a community of volunteers here, not professionals whose job is to support Ubuntu. If you want to get good (and helpful) support, you need to put in enough effort for us to be able to give it to you.

Comment: See also [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Comment: @Terrance when i click on it it takes me to another site, the stack exchange home where it shows another login option, not logout. also, this reputation system is insane, this question is meta but i couldn't ask on meta because i don't have enough rep. c'mon, this is just stupid.. at least nikhil was helpful providing me a link to do it.

Comment: Look at the Possible duplicate here.  The one I am talking about is in the second answer there.  BTW, we all start somewhere on this site.  I earned my points by helping with edits first, then worked my way up from there.  Also, take your time to ask a good question.  We are not mind readers here and we are all volunteers.  I spend time from my day to help people here and I enjoy it, but it makes it tough when all someone wants to do is to complain.

Comment: @KazWolfe the problem is that this community expects ppl to already know what are the standards. there is no direction for a new user on how to actually do things, it's not intuitive. and if you try to ask how to actually learn it, you can't because you don't have enough reputation. i can't mark this as solved (with the link provided by nikhil) because i need at least 15 rep. i can't ask on meta as i should because i need at leat 5 rep. ppl delete things from the original post and move around the question without me even knowing. you r all volunteers, but this is not helping at all.

Comment: @FelipeTam We expect users to (at the very least) read the [tour] to get a basic idea about how the site works. This is why, normally, when someone asks a new question and it's not up to the standard, we link them to the tour and the How To Ask page. We believe in learn by doing here. See our [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/) as well to see how reputation works. And, as always, the [help] is a great resource to start your journey here at this site. I'm sorry your initial experience was an unpleasant one.

Comment: @KazWolfe fair enough, but the problem is that none of that is easy to find. the interface is too poluted to make it easy for a newcomer like me to learn how to do it. and there r too many restrictions in place to make it understandable. i should have read the tour, surely, but damn, i couldn't even find it. or even knew there was one. when u ask for help, you don't expect to first have to learn how you r supposed to do it, you need help. afterwards, you might try to learn it all if pointed in the right direction (as you just did point me, thanks), but the site is messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Click on this [link](https://askubuntu.com/users/logout) to logout.

https://askubuntu.com/users/logout

Comment: thanks, your link actually works. it was the only helpfull comment here. yet i can't upvote you because i don't have enough reputation for it. see what i mean when i say this system is insane?

Comment: @FelipeTam You can accept their answer by clicking the grey checkmark. See our [tour] for an explanation of this. The system is not insane, it's designed to prevent abuse. Imagine if someone just created tons of new accounts to give themselves points by upvoting their own posts hundreds of times.

Comment: I TRIED. it says i need at least 15 reputation. the whole site is very counter intuitive and so restrictive that it does more harm than good. it completely put me off using linux (as others from what i've been reading). being a volunteer is about giving help, if i gotta keep jumping through hoops all the time to ask for help, you r not being helpfull. if you call emergency services and you can't connect because you r not important enough (reputation), what the fuck is it for? the idea here is great, but execution is totally messed up.