# links to Logout page

Tags: support, login

I found a page ([Log out of the site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17394/log-out-of-the-site)) that answers the question on how to logout of Ask Ubuntu, so I have the link (https://askubuntu.com/users/logout) which I can bookmark and use that every time I want to logout, but that seems awkward.  Isn't there a link/button in either the regular questions/answers pages or in my account/profile pages?  I've been looking hard for a while but can't find it.

Right now I'm logged in to "Ask Ubuntu" but NOT StackExchange, so the logout option from the StackExchange logo does not appear, that's normal.

I'm on Firefox, up-to-date.

Thank you.

Comment: I've got a screenshot for you here that'll point at it.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Thank you, that's it.  I never CLICKED on it, only hover and the tip "A list of all 172 Stack Exchange sites".  I thought it would be just that.  My error.  Now I'm looking for the "select this answer".  Don't tell me I'll find it.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm a moderator, I can't help but help users.  (To accept the answer, it's the checkbox under the voting options on the left side of an answer.)  Enjoy your continued use of Ask Ubuntu and the StackExchange network!  :)

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate though - [KazWolfe posted basically this answer on an exactly same question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17396/10616) (I just couldn't find it via my mobile device and VNC connecting to a desktop)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to ask as a comment to that original question but I don't have quite enough points yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still *technically* underneath the "logo" for StackExchange... but it's changed location and how the actual button looks like... it's at the right of the top bar, underneath a chat bubble-looking item that is meant to be the StackExchange logo, as shown in the screenshot below (freehand circles and arrows included for somewhat obvious reasons).

Click that icon (it's the one indicated by the arrow), and then you get the popup menu there.  The 'log out' button is there.  (it's the free-hand circle)

This screenshot is while looking at this exact question directly, here on Meta, but it's in the same place on the main site as well.

[image: Screenshot, with freehand circles and arrows]